# SonarQube scan on .ear

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1

I am new to Sonarqube. Can I perform code analysis of a .ear when I don't have source code available with me? Also, does it requires to set SonarQube locally? Any tutorial link would be most helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. SonarQube is looking at the source code at a minimum. So your first step is to obtain the source code!

Once you have the source code, you'll have a choice of:

- Install locally
- Install on a server
- Use the sonarqube.com cloud based scan

Comment: A third option would be to use SonarQube.com

Comment: Good point. I forgot about that. Edited to add to answer. Sagar still needs to find the code regardless!